# TsConfig.json path matching for all files in directory

Tags: typescript, import, path, glob, tsconfig

I have been looking into `tsconfig.json` and found that it can have paths created.
Currently the only way I can find that works is something like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src/app",
  "paths": {
    "@components": ["components/*"]
}
```

Which then allows me to do something like this:

```
import { dialogSale } from '@components/dialog-sale/dialog-sale.component';
```

This works fine however for my folder structure is a bit of a waist of time as my base path is already at app so I only have to do this which is actually 1 character shorter:

```
import { dialogSale } from 'components/dialog-sale/dialog-sale.component';
```

What I would like to do to shorten my import statements as well as to reduce developer error with sub directories is to be able to use like this:

```
import { dialogSale } from '@components/dialog-sale.component';
```

Above would be the most ideal as it reduces the chance of developer error as well as straight and to the point for import statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it shorter you should further specify your paths.
For example:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src/app",
  "paths": {
    "@components": ["components/dialog-sale/*"]
 }
}
```

and then you could use:

```
import { dialogSale } from '@components/dialog-sale.component';
```

This would not be really practical if you later want to add other 'components' different from dialog-sale.. In that case you could do:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src/app",
  "paths": {
    "@dialogSale": ["components/dialog-sale/*"]
 }
}
```

and use:

```
import { dialogSale } from '@dialogSale/dialog-sale.component';
```

Depending on how it works best for you. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Leslie forgot about this post actually. I will mark it write as this is correct but if you could also add a more inclusive glob pattern such as 'components/**/*' that would be great as then its any file within 'components' and not just in 'components/dialog-sale' which is even better. Thanks